# How does doc2vec.infer_vector combine across words?

Tags: python, gensim, doc2vec

I trained a doc2vec model using train(..) with default settings. That worked, but now I'm wondering how infer_vector combines across input words, is it just the average of the individual word vectors?

```
model.random.seed(0)
model.infer_vector(['cat', 'hat'])
model.random.seed(0)
model.infer_vector(['cat'])
model.infer_vector(['hat']) #doesn't average up to the ['cat', 'hat'] vector
model.random.seed(0)
model.infer_vector(['hat'])
model.infer_vector(['cat']) #doesn't average up to the ['cat', 'hat'] vector
```

Those don't add up, so I'm wondering what I'm misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`infer_vector()` doesn't combine the vectors for your given tokens – and in some modes doesn't consider those tokens' vectors at all.

Rather, it considers the entire Doc2Vec model as being frozen against internal changes, and then assumes the tokens you've provided are an example text, with a previously untrained tag. Let's call this implied but unnamed tag *X*.

Using a training-like process, it tries to find a good vector for *X*. That is, it starts with a random vector (as it did for all tags in original training), then sees how well that vector as model-input predicts the text's words (by checking the model neural-network's predictions for input *X*). Then via incremental gradient descent it makes that candidate vector for *X* better and better at predicting the text's words.

After enough such inference-training, the vector will be about as good (given the rest of the frozen model) as it possibly can be at predicting the text's words. So even though you're providing that text as an "input" to the method, inside the model, what you've provided is used to pick target "outputs" of the algorithm for optimization.

Note that:

- tiny examples (like one or a few words) aren't likely to give very meaningful results – they are sharp-edged corner cases, and the essential value of these sorts of dense embedded representations usually arises from the marginal balancing of many word-influences
- it will probably help to do far more training-inference cycles than the `infer_vector()` default `steps=5` – some have reported tens or hundreds of `steps` work best for them, and it may be especially valuable to use more `steps` with short texts
- it may also help to use a starting `alpha` for inference more like that used in bulk training (`alpha=0.025`), rather than the `infer_vector()` default (`alpha=0.1`)